# How to get employee name and id who have two phone numbers in second table

Tags: join, common-table-expression, derived-table

[image]

These are two tables 1. emp_table, 2. phone_table.
How to get employee name and id who have two phone numbers in second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
FROM emp_table t1
INNER JOIN                   -- the join will remove employees who do not have
(                            -- two phone numbers in phone_table
    SELECT Id
    FROM phone_table         -- this query identifies all employees
    GROUP BY Id              -- having two phone numbers in phone_table
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.Id
```